# Measure time to get DHCP address?

Tags: networking, dhcp

Is there any tool or way to measure how much time your DHCP router needs to give you IP address? I'm sure that there is something, as it's pretty important when debugging network.

Answer (score 1):

`dhcping` written by Edwin Groothuis, edwin@mavetju.org (http://www.mavetju.org) is what I use for troubleshooting dhcp, It has been a while since I used it so I don't remember if it reports time, but you can change the timeout which defaults to 3 seconds.